# How to play m3u8 audio file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

Don't know how to play m3u8 audio file in Flutter.
I searched for information about this, but what I found either did not work or was useless.
Help please!

P.S: I need this to work on Windows too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m3u8` is not an audio file - it's a text file with links pointing to the actual files.

That said, I think [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) can help you.

You just need to install and import the package, then put a controller like this somewhere:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network('your.m3u8');
    ChewieController chewieController;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        chewieController = ChewieController(
            videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
        );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Flutter Demo"),
            ),
            body: Container(
                child: Chewie(controller: chewieController),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I'm sure there'll be more documentation for your specific use case. There are settings like `autoPlay`, `aspectRatio`, and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Snx, but chewie does not support windows.